# How to overide the css

Tags: css

I am trying to override the css but not working.How do it?

```
.component.img.white *:not(.btn){
color:#fff;
}
```

trying to achive this:

```
 .component.img.white *:not(.btn){
  color:none !important;
  }
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: `none` is not a valid css value for color.

Comment: `color: none` is not valid I assume, you could try something like `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`

Comment: `color: transparent!important`

Comment: you could have tried `color:transparent` as none is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
.component.img.white *:not(.btn){
  color: inherit;
  }
```

it'll take a parent value or just set value explicitly

Answer (score 6):

**None** is not **valid** css **color**

```
.component.img.white *:not(.btn){
 color: transparent !important;
}
```

or you can use

```
.component.img.white *:not(.btn){
 color: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: How to remove totaly color property?